# Why is get_field_name_display() not working?

Tags: python, django

I have some code that uses [`get_field_name_display()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get%5FFOO%5Fdisplay).

Here's what's going on:

```
class Obj(models.model):
  CHOICES = ((0, 'Foo'),
             (1, 'Bar'),
             (2, 'Baz'))
  x = models.IntegerField(choices=CHOICES)
  description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  ...


obj = Obj(x=0)
obj.description = obj.get_x_display() + ' ' + obj.id
obj.description # Expected: 'Foo 21'
```

This code works fine in the shell, however when the code runs in a development server, the resulting description is `0 21`. What is going on?

Note that saving the object before calling `get_x_display()` does not fix this for me. Fetching a new copy of the object from the database *does*, but that's horrible and I'd much rather not do that.

Comment: Which Django version do you use ?

Comment: Just wonder how do you add `obj.get_x_display() + ' ' + obj.id` without `TypeError`.

Answer (score -2):

try to use

```
class Obj(models.model):
    CHOICES = ((0, 'Foo'),
         (1, 'Bar'),
         (2, 'Baz'))
    x = models.IntegerField(choices=CHOICES)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)



   @property
   def nu(self):
       return self.get_x_display()
```

and in :obj.description = obj.nu + ' ' + obj.id`